# Automating download of Google Trends Data in the Post 2014 World

Tags: google-trends

I've tried a number of the solutions (e.g. pyGTrends) found here and suggested by others and had code of my own functioning several years ago, but it appears that at some point Google has changed the way Trends is accessed or at least the authorization required to download it.

Can anyone share code that downloads (with authentication) Google Trends data?  Do I need to use OAuth 2.0 somehow.

I'm obviously completely in the dark here.